# Binomial Approximation. Calculate $n$

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have the next question: If it is known that $P(X \geq300)=0.3$ and $X \sim \mathop{Bin}(n,0.2)$ How can one estimate $n$?

Comment: Approximately 1460?

Comment: http://www.vassarstats.net/binomialX.html and javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Normal approximation**. Our binomial random variable $X$ has mean $(0.2)n$ and variance $(n)(0.2)(0.8)$, so standard deviation $0.4\sqrt{n}$.

Looking "backwards" in the table of the standard normal, we find that the probability that a standard normal $Z$ is $\ge z$ is $0.3$ for $z\approx 0.525$. 
But
$$\Pr(X\ge 300)\approx \Pr\left(Z\ge \frac{300-0.2n}{0.4\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
Thus we want to choose $n$ so that
$$\frac{300-0.2n}{0.4\sqrt{n}}\approx 0.525.$$
Let us pretend we have equality. Then we want to solve the equation $300-0.2n=(0.4)(0.525)\sqrt{n}$, or equivalently
$$0.2n +(0.4)(0.525)\sqrt{n}-300=0.$$
Make the substitution $x=\sqrt{n}$. We get a quadratic equation in $x$. Solve for $x$, using the Quadratic Formula, and square the result to estimate the appropriate $n$.

Comment: This really helped thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.